# How to define sequencing or dependency of one pod to another

Tags: openshift

In docker compose we have "depends_on" tag, to define denpendancy of one container on another to start.
example :

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
.
.
.
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - couchdb
```

Is there similar way in openshift to define dependency ?

Comment: Have a look to see whether StatefulSets may be able to help in your use case. These are beta in 1.7 of Kubernetes and are a replacement for PetSets from earlier versions. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [Readiness Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) to check any dependencies, for example by making HTTP calls to check that the required pods are up.  When these probes fail the pod won't show up in the endpoints of the corresponding Service so won't receive any traffic this way - for example via an Ingress.  Once the dependent pods are up then your pod will be considered available as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should build your services so that they can be brought up in any order.

In Kubernetes, one of the ways you can ensure that another service is alive before you go into the startup is to wait for availability in an initContainer.

The world is not ideal though, and sometimes you really need dependencies, afaik Mirantis had this problem for deployment of OpenStack control plane on K8S, which resulted in https://github.com/Mirantis/k8s-AppController